# Change RouteConfig to display long name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there a way to edit the route config to get the long ugly name? Here's the default route from a VS2015

**RouteConfig:**MVC 5 template

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**update for clarification:**

something like this

```
domain.com/blog/index.cshtml    // < -- I know this isn't correct
```

rather than this

```
domain.com/blog
```

Comment: What do you mean by _get the long ugly name_? Perhaps give some examples of what your trying and what the actual result and expected result is.

Comment: updated for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that as the resource you're accessing isn't `Index.cshtml`, but the "Index" action.  The action returns a `ViewResult` which searches for the page to render using the View Engine.  The page could be in the controller directory, the shared directory, or could be .cshtml, .vbhtml, ect.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

Comment: After learning a bit more about MVC, I've decided to revisit this post and mark this as the answer. Thanks Ashley

Answer (score 1):

In MVC if you are going to map your physical file in route then by default mvc ignores your routing part.so you can do map you index.cshtml file in routing.

You can write your code like this :

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/Details.aspx",
        defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have to follow the MVC URL pattern but you can change the controller Name and Controller Method name in URL. Assume that the controller name is ILoveMyVeryBigNameController and the controller method name is IsMyControolerMethodNameIsToUgly and domain is : domain.com then in RouteConfig.cs

//Route mapping for ILoveMyVeryBigNameController 
            routes.MapRoute(name: "ILoveMyVeryBigName", url: "ILove/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ILoveMyVeryBigNameController", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

the above route mapping must be put before general route mapping

and in controller method you put the attribute:
[Route("ILove/Ugly/{id}")]
public ActionResult IsMyControolerMethodNameIsToUgly (string id)...

**NOTE : I believe you are using MVC 5 or above version**

Thanks
Raviranjan